# Cómo arreglo la pantalla

Tags: vb.net, botón, vb, vb6

Estoy iniciando un proyecto en `VisualBasic 6`, en el cual necesito que por medio de un botón se añadan más `TextBox/CheckBox/ComboBox.` 
El problema es que al momento de añadirlos, se descompagina la pantalla.

Adjunto las imágenes para una mejor compresión:

**Así es el formulario creado** (Lo que está dentro del Frame se debe mostrar luego de presionado el botón. (El index en 0 y el visible en false)):

[image: Vista de la edición del formulario]

Cuando inicio la aplicación se ve así:

[image: Vista del formulario en ejecución]

Y cuando presiono el botón sucede esto:

[image: Vista del formulario en ejecución]

[image: Vista del formulario en ejecución]

La idea es que se vea como en la primera imagen, en la que muestro el formulario creado.

Este es todo el código que utilizo:

```
Dim indice As Integer

Private Sub btnAñadir_Click()
indice = indice + 1 ' aumentamos el index

' frmAñadir
Load frmAñadir(indice) ' creamos el control
frmAñadir(indice).Visible = True ' lo hacemos visible
frmAñadir(indice).Top = frmAñadir(indice - 1).Top + frmAñadir(indice).Height ' movemos el control

'cmbAddTipo
Load cmbAddTipo(indice)
cmbAddTipo(indice).Visible = True
cmbAddTipo(indice).Top = cmbAddTipo(indice - 1).Top + cmbAddTipo(indice).Height

'txtAddPrefijo
Load txtAddPrefijo(indice)
txtAddPrefijo(indice).Visible = True
txtAddPrefijo(indice).Top = txtAddPrefijo(indice - 1).Top + txtAddPrefijo(indice).Height

'txtAddNumero
Load txtAddNumero(indice)
txtAddNumero(indice).Visible = True
txtAddNumero(indice).Top = txtAddNumero(indice - 1).Top + txtAddNumero(indice).Height

'checkAddPrincipal
Load checkAddPrincipal(indice)
checkAddPrincipal(indice).Visible = True
checkAddPrincipal(indice).Top = checkAddPrincipal(indice - 1).Top + checkAddPrincipal(indice).Height

'cmbAddVinculo
Load cmbAddVinculo(indice)
cmbAddVinculo(indice).Visible = True
cmbAddVinculo(indice).Top = cmbAddVinculo(indice - 1).Top + cmbAddVinculo(indice).Height

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que encontré fue la siguiente, añadir los elementos dentro de un UserControl y desde ahí cargarlos. Adjunto el código por si alguien lo llega a necesitar:

```
Dim indice As Integer
Dim indicee As Integer

Private Sub btnAñadir_Click()
indice = indice + 1 'aumentamos el index
indicee = indicee + 0 'lo iniciamos en 0
uc1(indicee).Visible = True

'Label y TextBox de tipo
lblTipo(indicee).Visible = True
cmbAddTipo(indicee).Visible = True

'Label y TextBox de prefijo
lblAddPrefijo(indicee).Visible = True
txtAddPrefijo(indicee).Visible = True

'Label y TextBox de número
lblAddNum(indicee).Visible = True
txtAddNumero(indicee).Visible = True

chkAddPrincipal(indicee).Visible = True

'Label y TextBox de vínculo
lblAddVin(indicee).Visible = True
cmbAddVinculo(indicee).Visible = True

'uc1
Load uc1(indice) ' creamos el control
uc1(indice).Visible = True ' lo hacemos visible
uc1(indice).Top = uc1(indice - 1).Top + uc1(indice - 1).Height + 20

'lblTipo
Load lblTipo(indice)
Set lblTipo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
lblTipo(indice).Visible = True
lblTipo(indice).Top = lblTipo(indice - 1).Top
'cmbAddTipo
Load cmbAddTipo(indice)
Set cmbAddTipo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
cmbAddTipo(indice).Visible = True
cmbAddTipo(indice).Top = cmbAddTipo(indice - 1).Top

'lblAddPrefijo
Load lblAddPrefijo(indice)
Set lblAddPrefijo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
lblAddPrefijo(indice).Visible = True
lblAddPrefijo(indice).Top = lblAddPrefijo(indice - 1).Top
'txtAddPrefijo
Load txtAddPrefijo(indice)
Set txtAddPrefijo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
txtAddPrefijo(indice).Visible = True
txtAddPrefijo(indice).Top = txtAddPrefijo(indice - 1).Top

'lblAddNum
Load lblAddNum(indice)
Set lblAddNum(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
lblAddNum(indice).Visible = True
lblAddNum(indice).Top = lblAddNum(indice - 1).Top
'txtAddNumero
Load txtAddNumero(indice)
Set txtAddNumero(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
txtAddNumero(indice).Visible = True
txtAddNumero(indice).Top = txtAddNumero(indice - 1).Top

'checkAddPrincipal
Load chkAddPrincipal(indice)
Set chkAddPrincipal(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
chkAddPrincipal(indice).Visible = True
chkAddPrincipal(indice).Top = chkAddPrincipal(indice - 1).Top

'lblAddVin
Load lblAddVin(indice)
Set lblAddVin(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
lblAddVin(indice).Visible = True
lblAddVin(indice).Top = lblAddVin(indice - 1).Top
'cmbAddVinculo
Load cmbAddVinculo(indice)
Set cmbAddVinculo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
cmbAddVinculo(indice).Visible = True
cmbAddVinculo(indice).Top = cmbAddVinculo(indice - 1).Top

End Sub
```